# Calculating Prime Numbers in MIPS Assembly

Tags: assembly, mips, pcspim

I am currently working on a program that calculates the prime numbers up to 200 using recursion in MIPS assembly using PCSPIM. So far, I have populated an array of numbers from 1-200 and a binary vector list that consists of all 1's successfully. The concept that I am struggling with is how to use a stack frame to help with the process.

Here is what I have for the stack frame:

```
 subu  $sp,$sp,32       # Set up the stack frame
 sw    $ra, 28($sp)     # save $ra register to the stack
 sw    $fp, 24($sp)     # save $fp register to the stack
 addu  $fp, $sp, 28     # set $fp register to the end of the stack
```

I just don't understand how this is going to help me find prime numbers. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Before the code, are you clear with the algorithm?

Comment: _"I just don't understand how this is going to help me find prime numbers."_ It helps you perform recursive calls, since you need to save and restore `$ra` (and possibly other registers) somehow, and you say that your algorithm is recursive.

Comment: starrify, I am completely clear with the algorithm. If I had to do it in a high level language, I could definitely do it. I just don't understand how to do it in MIPS.

Comment: @dhint4 Fine. Then Michael's comment is also what I wanna say. Also ask Google for how to implement recursion in low level languages like MIPS assembly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with the sieve of Eratosthenes, you don't need recursion to find prime numbers. This method is much simpler and more memory-efficient than using recursion, and you don't need to use the stack.

I can't help you with "how this is going to help me find prime numbers", because you never specified what algorithm you're using.